# django tables2 checkbox

Tags: django, checkbox, header, django-tables2

I'm new to programming so this may be a trivial question...

In django-tables2, I'd like to be able to display the column header name when using CheckBoxColumn. Right now, all the checkboxes are displaying for each row, including in the header. I don't mind having a checkbox in the header (I figure that would be a great way to do a "select all" in the long run), but I need the column name to display. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Could you post some code ?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom checkbox column class that inherits from tables.CheckBoxColumn
then override the render method, then specify the check box together with its label as html response.

```
class CustomCheckBoxColumn(tables.CheckBoxColumn):

    def render(self, value, record, bound_column):
        return mark_safe(u'column Name<input type=checkbox, … />')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [`TemplateColumn()`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#templatecolumn) instead of `CheckBoxColumn()`

```
template = '<input type="checkbox" name="{{record.name}}" />'
checkbox_column_header = tables.TemplateColumn(template)
```