# django-tables2 CheckBoxColumn header

Tags: checkbox, header, django-tables2

How can I get django-tables2 CheckBoxColumn to honour the provided verbose_name?

If I define a CheckBoxColumn thus:

force_flag = tables.CheckBoxColumn(accessor=('force_flag'), attrs = { "th__input": {"id": "selectAllForce"}}, verbose_name='Force?', orderable=False)

the table is rendered but the column header is simply a checkbox and does not use the verbose_name.

This question has been asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419385/django-tables2-checkbox) but unless I do not fully understand the answer I cannot see that working.  Reading the suggested code, I would imagine that this would add the string 'column Name' to each row data value.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is under investigation/discussion by the author of django-tables2 on [GitHib](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/pull/117)